# Неопределенное количество рекурсии SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, рекурсия

Имеются три таблицы:

**data_report** - исходные данные с нужными номерами узлов

| id | node_number | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20923 |  |
| 2 | 20328 |  |
| 3 | 20589 |  |

**node** - соотношение id узла и номера узла

| id | node_id | number | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 700 | 20823 |  |
| 2 | 701 | 20328 |  |
| 3 | 702 | 20589 |  |
| 4 | 704 | 30142 |  |
| 5 | 809 | 40144 |  |

**node_relations** - отношение между узлам (у узлов есть подузлы - в поле head_node_id указывается головной узел)

| id | node_id | head_node_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 704 | 702 |  |
| 74 | 809 | 704 |  |

Необходимо извлечь информацию о узлах и подузлах из таблице [node], номера которых взять в таблице [data_report]

Я смог додуматься только до такого решения:

```
WITH nodes_from_data_report AS (
    SELECT node_id FROM node WHERE node_number IN (SELECT data_report.node_number FROM data_report)
), nodes_from_recursive_one AS (
    SELECT node_relationships.node_id FROM node_relationships WHERE head_node_id IN (SELECT * FROM nodes_from_data_report)
), nodes_from_recursive_two AS (
    SELECT node_relationships.node_id FROM node_relationships WHERE head_node_id IN (SELECT * FROM nodes_from_recursive_one)
), nodes_from_recursive_three AS (
    SELECT node_relationships.node_id FROM node_relationships WHERE head_node_id IN (SELECT * FROM nodes_from_recursive_two)
), union_all_nodes AS (
    SELECT * FROM nodes_from_data_report
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM nodes_from_recursive_one
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM nodes_from_recursive_two
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM nodes_from_recursive_three
)
SELECT [node].[id]
      ,[node].[node_id]
      ,[node].[node_number]
      ,[node].[description]
      ,[node].[count]
      ,[node].[other_info]
  FROM [TestRecursive].[dbo].[node]
  WHERE node_id IN (SELECT * FROM union_all_nodes)
```

Самая главная проблема, которую вижу я - это необходимость знать уровень вложенности узлов.
Хотелось бы, чтобы он продолжал отпускаться вниз пока не кончатся узлы или пока не будет произведено n погружений (на случай, если там есть зацикливание). Буду рад любой помощи!

Код для создания мини базы для тестов:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [TestRecursive]    Script Date: 28.09.2022 9:42:50 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [TestRecursive]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'TestRecursive', FILENAME = N'D:\DATA\TestRecursive.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'TestRecursive_log', FILENAME = N'D:\logs\TestRecursive_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150
GO
IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
begin
EXEC [TestRecursive].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
end
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET ARITHABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET  DISABLE_BROKER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET RECOVERY FULL 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET  MULTI_USER 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 60 SECONDS 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = DISABLED 
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET ACCELERATED_DATABASE_RECOVERY = OFF  
GO
EXEC sys.sp_db_vardecimal_storage_format N'TestRecursive', N'ON'
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET QUERY_STORE = OFF
GO
USE [TestRecursive]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[data_report]    Script Date: 28.09.2022 9:42:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[data_report](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [node_number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [description] [nchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[node]    Script Date: 28.09.2022 9:42:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[node](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [node_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [node_number] [int] NULL,
    [description] [nchar](50) NULL,
    [count] [int] NULL,
    [other_info] [nchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[node_relationships]    Script Date: 28.09.2022 9:42:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[node_relationships](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [node_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [head_node_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [other_info] [nchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[Recursive]    Script Date: 28.09.2022 9:42:50 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Recursive]
AS
WITH nodes_from_data_report AS (SELECT        node_id
                                                                            FROM            dbo.node
                                                                            WHERE        (node_number IN
                                                                                                         (SELECT        node_number
                                                                                                           FROM            dbo.data_report))), nodes_from_recursive_one AS
    (SELECT        node_id
      FROM            dbo.node_relationships
      WHERE        (head_node_id IN
                                    (SELECT        node_id
                                      FROM            nodes_from_data_report AS nodes_from_data_report_2))), nodes_from_recursive_two AS
    (SELECT        node_id
      FROM            dbo.node_relationships AS node_relationships_2
      WHERE        (head_node_id IN
                                    (SELECT        node_id
                                      FROM            nodes_from_recursive_one AS nodes_from_recursive_one_2))), nodes_from_recursive_three AS
    (SELECT        node_id
      FROM            dbo.node_relationships AS node_relationships_1
      WHERE        (head_node_id IN
                                    (SELECT        node_id
                                      FROM            nodes_from_recursive_two AS nodes_from_recursive_two_2))), union_all_nodes AS
    (SELECT        node_id
      FROM            nodes_from_data_report AS nodes_from_data_report_1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT        node_id
      FROM            nodes_from_recursive_one AS nodes_from_recursive_one_1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT        node_id
      FROM            nodes_from_recursive_two AS nodes_from_recursive_two_1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT        node_id
      FROM            nodes_from_recursive_three AS nodes_from_recursive_three_1)
    SELECT        id, node_id, node_number, description, count, other_info
     FROM            dbo.node AS node_1
     WHERE        (node_id IN
                                  (SELECT        node_id
                                    FROM            union_all_nodes AS union_all_nodes_1))
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[data_report] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_report] ([id], [node_number], [description]) VALUES (1, 20923, N'Узел 1 для отчёта                                 ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_report] ([id], [node_number], [description]) VALUES (2, 20328, N'Узел 2 для отчёта                                 ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[data_report] ([id], [node_number], [description]) VALUES (3, 20589, N'Узел 3 для отчёта                                 ')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[data_report] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[node] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[node] ([id], [node_id], [node_number], [description], [count], [other_info]) VALUES (1, 700, 20923, N'Информация о узле 20923                           ', 4, N'Какая-то инфа 1                                   ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[node] ([id], [node_id], [node_number], [description], [count], [other_info]) VALUES (2, 701, 20328, N'Информация о узле 20328                           ', 1, N'Какая-то инфа 2                                   ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[node] ([id], [node_id], [node_number], [description], [count], [other_info]) VALUES (3, 702, 20589, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[node] ([id], [node_id], [node_number], [description], [count], [other_info]) VALUES (4, 704, 30142, N'Информация о узле 30142                           ', NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[node] ([id], [node_id], [node_number], [description], [count], [other_info]) VALUES (5, 809, 40144, N'Информация о узле 809                             ', 20, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[node] ([id], [node_id], [node_number], [description], [count], [other_info]) VALUES (6, 901, 21541, NULL, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[node] ([id], [node_id], [node_number], [description], [count], [other_info]) VALUES (7, 1002, 50478, NULL, NULL, N'Какая-то инфа 7                                   ')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[node] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[node_relationships] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[node_relationships] ([id], [node_id], [head_node_id], [other_info]) VALUES (1, 704, 702, N'Информация об отношениях 1                        ')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[node_relationships] ([id], [node_id], [head_node_id], [other_info]) VALUES (2, 809, 704, N'Информация об отношениях 2                        ')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[node_relationships] OFF
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPane1', @value=N'[0E232FF0-B466-11cf-A24F-00AA00A3EFFF, 1.00]
Begin DesignProperties = 
   Begin PaneConfigurations = 
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 0
         NumPanes = 4
         Configuration = "(H (1[40] 4[20] 2[20] 3) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 1
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 4 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 2
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1 [50] 2 [25] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 3
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (4 [30] 2 [40] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 4
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [56] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 5
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (2 [66] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 6
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [50] 3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 7
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (3))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 8
         NumPanes = 3
         Configuration = "(H (1[56] 4[18] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 9
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1 [75] 4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 10
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (1[66] 2) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 11
         NumPanes = 2
         Configuration = "(H (4 [60] 2))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 12
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(H (1) )"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 13
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (4))"
      End
      Begin PaneConfiguration = 14
         NumPanes = 1
         Configuration = "(V (2))"
      End
      ActivePaneConfig = 0
   End
   Begin DiagramPane = 
      Begin Origin = 
         Top = 0
         Left = 0
      End
      Begin Tables = 
         Begin Table = "node_1"
            Begin Extent = 
               Top = 6
               Left = 38
               Bottom = 136
               Right = 208
            End
            DisplayFlags = 280
            TopColumn = 0
         End
      End
   End
   Begin SQLPane = 
   End
   Begin DataPane = 
      Begin ParameterDefaults = ""
      End
   End
   Begin CriteriaPane = 
      Begin ColumnWidths = 11
         Column = 1440
         Alias = 900
         Table = 1170
         Output = 720
         Append = 1400
         NewValue = 1170
         SortType = 1350
         SortOrder = 1410
         GroupBy = 1350
         Filter = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
         Or = 1350
      End
   End
End
' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'Recursive'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_DiagramPaneCount', @value=1 , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'VIEW',@level1name=N'Recursive'
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [TestRecursive] SET  READ_WRITE 
GO
```

Comment: В SQL есть такое понятие как "common table expression" (CTE). Это как временное безымянное представление (VIEW), используемое в одном SELECT'е. CTE бывают рекурсивными, в SELECT обозначаются ключевым словом WITH. Советую почитать справку в этом направлении

Comment: Отделите код создания и наполнения таблиц от своего решения и удалите ненужную шелуху (лишние поля, индексы, установки). Покажите требуемый ответ для именно этих данных. См. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169) Особенно пункты 2.3 и 5.